# Lines In the Complex Proyective Plane

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry

The question is In how many points a line in CP^n intersects CP^2?.

By a line in CP, I mean a copy from CP^1. I have tried with a sytem of equations, (Because a line in CP^n is the zero locus of a polynomial in n-variables of degree 1) and watch if that line passes throug one point or two.

I have this:

Let $p_{1}, p_{2},p_{3} \in \mathbb{C}P^{n}$ points whose coordinates are:

$p_{1} = [1:\frac{x_{1}}{x_{0}}: \ldots:\frac{x_{n}}{x_{0}}], p_{2} = [1:\frac{z_{1}}{z_{0}}:\frac{z_{2}}{z_{0}} \ldots:0], p_{3} = [1:\frac{c_{1}}{c_{0}}:\frac{c_{2}}{c_{0}} \ldots:0] $

Notice that althought the points are in $\mathbb{C}P^{n}$, $p{2},p{3} \in \mathbb{C}P^{2}$.

Then, we want to know if there exist a line in the projective space such that passes throught these three points.

Since a line in  $\mathbb{C}P^{n}$ is the zero locus of a polynomial in n-variables of degree 1 then we have the next system of equations:

$$x_{0} + x_{1}(\frac{x_{1}}{x_{0}}) + \ldots + x_{n}(\frac{x_{n}}{x_{0}}) = 0 \\
x_{0} + x_{1}(\frac{z_{1}}{z_{0}}) + x_{2}(\frac{z_{2}}{z_{0}}) = 0 \\
x_{0} + x_{1}(\frac{c_{1}}{c_{0}}) + x_{2}(\frac{c_{2}}{c_{0}}) = 0 $$

Then I did a matrix with this system and I proved that the linear tranformation associated to the matrix is not inyective, but my result is that given 3 points there is only on line that passes through them and that can´nt be. What did I do wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: A line not included in a plane meets that plane in at most 1 point.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that $\Bbb P^n(\Bbb C)$ is the quotient of $\Bbb C^{n+1}\setminus\{0\}$ under the parallelism equivalence of vectors in $\Bbb C^{n+1}$ and there's a quotient map
$$
\pi:\Bbb C^{n+1}\setminus\{0\}\longrightarrow\Bbb P^n(\Bbb C)
$$
under which the linear subspaces in the target correspond under inverse image to vector subspaces in the source space with $0$ taken out of diension raised by $1$.

Thus $V=\pi^{-1}(\Bbb P^2)\cup\{0\}$ is a subspace of dimension $3$ and $W=\pi^{-1}(\text{line})\cup\{0\}$ is a subspace of dimension $2$.

If $W\subset V$, the line sits inside the plane.

If $dim(V\cap W)=1$ the line and the plane intersect in one point.

If $n\geq4$ it may happen that $V\cap W=\{0\}$ and in this case there is no intersection between line and plane.

Comment: Than you Andrea, but can you expalin in detail that function and the linear subspaces please, I am an undergraduate hahahhahaha, thank you

Comment: I have another question, Can you explain me these two things please:f dim(V∩W)=1 the line and the plane intersect in one point.

If n≥4 it may happen that V∩W={0} and in this case there is no intersection between line and plane.

Comment: A $1$-dimensional subspace consists of parallel vectors, and they define just one point in projective space. If the intersection is trivial, $V$ and $W$ have no intersection once you remove the $0$-vector.

Comment: Yes, I undestand that but, the function and the other things, how can you Claim them without a prove?, Thank you.

Comment: if you really want to use equations, the discussion boils down to the Rouche-Capelli Theorem. I'll leave the (boring) details to you as an exercise. :)

Comment: Ok thank You Andrea, I´ll do it later I´ll tell you if I could solve it or not. :)

Comment: Andrea I´m sorry but I tried that too, I know that like Rouche-Frobenius Theorem, but Is no-square matrix hahahaha :)

Comment: That`s why I liked your answer, but I´m a undergraduate and I don´t undersatand that things,thank you.